# ADB exited with exit code -1 Performing Push Install

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart, flutter-layout

while I am working on a new project I got this error when I try to install it on my physical device. I thought it was my project error. but when I run the default flutter project I got this same error plz help me. how can I solve this[image]

Comment: Can you share your flutter doctor output?

Comment: try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1288], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
    ! Device G8M9XA1792810831 is offline.

• No issues found!

Comment: Try restarting both your windows and android and then do a flutter clean and flutter pub get. This might solve your issue